# Between any two continuous functions $f>g$, can we find a real-analytic function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, power-series

I asked myself a question which I thought was interesting, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

### The Question

The question is, given two continuous functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f > g$, is there a real analytic function $h$ between $f$ and $g$ (so that $f > h > g$)?

---

An easier version of the question can be asked over closed intervals.
Given two continuous functions $f,g:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f > g$, is there a real analytic function $h$ between $f$ and $g$?

In this case, the answer is yes, and the result is actually stronger than expected.
Essentially, this is an application of the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem.

> By the extreme value theorem, the function $H(x) = (f(x) - g(x))/2$ has a   minimum $M > 0$. You can define $k(x) = (f(x) + g(x))/2$ and then apply the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem to get a polynomial $p:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lVert p - k\rVert < M$.
>   Then $p$ is a polynomial such that $p(x)\in (k(x) - M, k(x) + M)\subseteq (g(x), f(x))$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

---

However, you run into issues when the domain is the real line.
Here are some thoughts I had so far.

### For

I am aware that there is a generalized Stone-Weierstrass Theorem on locally compact Hausdorff spaces $X$ concerning functions in $C_{0}(X)$.
There are two issues though.
The first is that our continuous functions $f,g$ don't necessarily tend to zero as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$.
The second is that the difference $f(x) - g(x)$ is allowed to get arbitrarily small as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$.

The first issue isn't major to me, because I think I have a way to evade it.
For all intents and purposes, we can assume that $f,g$ tend to zero if it suits our needs.

The second issue, though, seems to be fatal, and it seems like there is no way to modify the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem appropriately.

This makes me think I need a completely different approach.

### Against

If I want to make a counterexample, maybe I can use pathological functions like the Weierstrass function $w:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
I'm thinking that if we take $f(x) = w(x) + e^{-x^{2}}$ and $g(x) = w(x)$, we can force any intermediate function $h$ to become "more and more detailed" as it gets sandwiched closer and closer between $f,g$ for large $x$.
Then this function might become "too detailed" to be analytic, but I have no rigorous way to express this idea.

Even worse, I'm having doubts that this would go anywhere because there is always "wiggle room" between $f$ and $g$, so maybe we can fit an analytic function between them after all.

---

Are there any suggestions on how to make progress on this question?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108132/does-for-every-continuous-function-fr-rightarrow-r-there-exist-a-sequence-o?rq=1, which gives an affirmative answer when $f-g > \epsilon$.

Comment: Indeed, the answer suggests that the Carleman paper referenced might actually prove the result you seek.  I haven't yet read the paper carefully enough to tell.

Comment: Possibly relevant google searches: ["sandwich theorem" + semicontinuous](https://www.google.com/search?q="sandwich+theorem"+semicontinuous) AND ["in-between theorem" + semicontinuous](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in-between%20theorem%22+semicontinuous)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@NateEldredge mentioned a result of Carleman. It is indeed a beautiful theorem: Suppose $G:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, and $\epsilon: \mathbb R \to (0,\infty)$ is any positive continuous function. Then there exists an entire function $F$ such that $|F(x)-G(x)| < \epsilon(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R.$

In your problem we can let $G = (f+g)/2$ and $\epsilon = (f-g)/2.$ Then

$$\frac{g-f}{2} < F - \frac{f+g}{2} < \frac{f-g}{2}\,\,\, \text {  on    }\,\, \mathbb R$$

and your result falls right out.