# Between every two Riemann-integrable functions there is at least one Riemann-nonintegrable function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, riemann-integration

I "created" this problem approximately 10-14 hours ago.

I think that this problem could be used as some undergraduate exercise in the chapter on Riemann integrability.

The meaning of *between* is the following:

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two Riemann-integrable functions defined on the closed interval $I$ and that $f<g$.

$f<g$ means that for every $x \in I$ it is true that $f(x)<g(x)$.

The function $h$ is between $f$ and $g$ if and only if $f<h<g$.

I think that different approaches exist to solve this exercise, and, which one would be yours?

One intuitive idea is to choose for every $f$ and $g$ some $h$ which is very *wildly discontinuous* in such a way for Riemann integral of $h$ to not exist.

But, I didn´t turn this idea into a concrete proof yet.

How to prove this?

Comment: @DavidMitra But that one is Riemann-integrable.

Comment: A counterexample to this statement would be rather pathological.  If $f$ and $g$ have distinct values within some interval, the statement is already true.

Comment: @DavidMitra That´s not allowed since $f<h<g$ everywhere in the interval.

Comment: Well, how about $h=(1/4)f+(3/4)g$ for the rationals and $h=(3/4)f+(1/4)g$ for the irrationals. The set of points where both $f$ and $g$ are continuous has positive measure; but at any such point, $h$ will be discontinuous, I think.

Comment: @DavidMitra That´s much much better, but I do not know how to prove that that construction always gives Riemann-nonintegrable $h$.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability) result?

Comment: @YamMir If $f$ and $g$ differ only in isolated points, the statement is false.

Comment: @DavidMitra Yes, a long time ago. So, your construction gives everywhere discontinuous $h$?

Comment: Perhaps not everywhere; but at least at any point $x$ where both $f$ and $g$ are continuous. So at every point  in a set of positive measure, $h$ is discontinuous (so, not integrable).

Comment: @DavidMitra I didn´t study seriously measure theory but if $A$ is a set of positive measure, does that mean that $A$ is an *almost-interval* (in some precisely defined sense and meaning)?

Comment: OK, what am I missing? Why can't we just let $h$ be the pointwise-defined arithmetic mean of $f$ and $g,$ namely for each $x$ we define $h(x) = \frac{f(x) + g(x)}{2}?$ Usually in considerations like this (e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=semicontinuous+insertion+theorem) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2561363/13130)), the in-between function $h$ is required to nicer than $f$ and $g$ are assumed to be. *(MOMENTS LATER)* Oh, I see. You want the in-between function to be non-Riemann integrable. Well, maybe my links could be helpful in suggesting search terms.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro That $h$ is Riemann-integrable.

Comment: Take $I=[0,1]$ for convenience. Since $f<g,$ for every $x\in I,\ g(x)-f(x)$ contains an interval. So, if every $h$ between $f$ and $g$ were Riemann integrable, then the cardinality of them would be $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$, but it is well-known that the cardinality is $2^{\frak c}$